# Why python shell stores last expression in _ variable but python file does not?

Tags: python, interpreter, pythoninterpreter

I ran below code in python shell and from a python file, I expected the same output but ironically i get `NameError: name '_' is not defined` error in python file.

```py
>>> 10+2
12
>>> print(_)
12
```

So i started wondering why python shell stores last expression in `_` variable but it is not even defined in python file.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Comment: Because *"last executed expression"* doesn't have a lot of meaning in an actual file (script)... It has a meaning when running an interactive shell...